# How to show a pdf response from external application as pdf on visual force page?

Tags: visualforce

I am getting a pdf response from an external application and I want to show that data as a pdf on the visualforce page. The data is showing on the page but in a non-readable format.

Comment: What code you have written to share the blob. Are you storing the PDF in Salesforce as well?

Comment: No , i am not storing the response in salesforce

Comment: Blob contentData =  res.getBodyAsBlob(); return EncodingUtil.base64Encode(contentData);

Answer (score 1):

As there is no standard way of doing this unless you are storing PDF in salesforce. So you need a third party library to display PDF in VF page. You can use [PDF.JS](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) for this as there are examples available for same Which you can refer.

One you can find [here](http://usefulangle.com/post/20/pdfjs-tutorial-1-preview-pdf-during-upload-wih-next-prev-buttons).

**Update:** I also find a native solution which you can use.

```
<apex:page controller="ViewPdf">
    <iframe src="data:{!att.ContentType};base64,{!pdf}" ></iframe>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class ViewPdf {
    public Attachment att {
        get {
            if (att == null) {
                att = [SELECT Body, ContentType, Name FROM Attachment WHERE ID = '00PG0000004COZU'];
            }
            return att;
        }
        private set;
    }
    public String pdf {
        get {
            return EncodingUtil.Base64Encode(att.body);
        }
    }
}
```

[Display a blob as a PDF on a Visualforce page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000044612&type=1)

But keep in mind if you are using `apex:form` in page you might hit the ViewState limit.

Comment: This is not working for me. My pdf is not showing data in the correct readable format.

Comment: @AmanJain I am using the first one in many projects and didn't face any error. You need to make sure your data is correct in first place.

Comment: pls don't suggest hardcode id.. and iframe is not good if he is creating appExchange product iFrame will not pass.

Comment: @cloudZigZag Thanks for the suggestion. But he didn't mention anywhere that this is for app exchange product. Also, this is a sample code pick from SF docs. This is expected to follow the general guidelines here.